# How to use a native .so with Glassfish 3.1

Tags: glassfish, native-methods

I am trying to build a web interface for an embedded device, that will display network statistics. I am using Glassfish 3.1 Application Server, and I would like to use jnetpcap to listen to network traffic. jnetpcap relies on the libpcap native libraries. I have tried to find documentation from Oracle about using native libraries with Glassfish, but I haven't found what I am looking for yet (and I may be looking for the wrong thing).

When my servlet loads it fails with

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jnetpcap.Pcap

which I interpret to mean, that the class loader can find the class (I have specified it as a library when I deploy it) but cannot load it. My first inferences were that it might have been a security policy problem, or that the jvm couldn't find the libpcap.so.

I set the path for system.library.path in the admin console (ie the web interface) using Configurations->server-config->jvm-settings. In the 'Path Settings' tab, I put the path '/usr/bin/libpcap.so' in the Native Library Path Suffix field. When I restarted the Glassfish server, I got the following message:

[#|2011-03-31T13:30:13.962+1100|WARNING|glassfish3.1|null| ... GlassFishConfigBean.com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.JavaConfig}, reason = JavaConfig attribute 'NativeLibraryPathSuffix' was changed from 'null' to '/usr/bin/libpcap.so', when = 1301538613961|#]

and later in the logs the native library path turns up in the path output

-Djava.library.path= ... /usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/bin/libpcap.so

so I think the native library is being successfully loaded. Is there a way that I can check that native library is indeed loaded?

I have also disabled the security manager (just for the time being, to try to get the servlet to work; I plan to implement more subtle security policies once it's working), and that hasn't fixed the problem either.

Am I trying to load the native library correctly? How can I find out more information about whether the native library is loaded, and about why the org.jnetpcap.Pcap class cannot be initialized?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, solved.

Problem was jnetpcap depends on libjnetpcap.so not libpcap.so. My mistake.

Added the path correct path (/stuff/ ... /libjnetpcap-1.3.b4) to the Native Library Path Suffix field of the JVM Path Settings, and it was all systems go.